# How not to repeat myself in Kohana 3's routes?

Tags: kohana

Let's say I want to make a system which can afford a multilingual web project. The system will consist of the modules that are put in Kohana's standard directory `modules`. Let's say that the standard access to the particular language can be done via `lang` parameter (i.e. somesite.com/**en**/somepage). The problem is that I have to repeat myself in defining my modules routes prepending each uri with `(<lang>)`. Is there any way to avoid that? I thought about a separate language route declaration (for example in bootstap.php file), but I guess it won't solve the problem.

It's all about Kohana 3. Thanks to all.

**UPDATE:**
I think that the way suggested by The Pixel Developer is what one need if some part of the rule in route repeats everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move up a level and extend the route class.

http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/classes/kohana/route.php#L69

```
public static function set($name, $uri, array $regex = NULL)
{
    return parent::set($name, '(<lang>)'.$uri, $regex);
}
```

Not tested, but that's the general idea.

Comment: hm. Interesting idea. Why I didn't think about it. I'll try it later and update the question.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it's correct. People will be more likely to help in the future if you have a high accept ratio.

Comment: Of course, I'll definitely do it right after I'll have tried it!

Answer (score 2):

If `lang` is required in route, why don't you just put it in the default route? Surely that's the easiest way to go about. Something like:

```
Route::set('default', '<lang>(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('lang'=> '[a-z]{2}'))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'somepage',
    'action'     => 'index',
    'lang'       => 'en',
));
```

Where lang is any 2 letters alphabets which defaults to 'en'.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand the routing system, but in such a case I'll have to put <lang> in each next route I'll define, shan't I? Now I can't verify all the ways I have already got here, but I guess that The Pixel Developer is right... In next several hours I'll try.

Comment: Yes you will need to put it for every routes. See this page for examples doing it more elegantly: http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=routing:multi-language_with_a_route